# Returning JSONResult without switching views

Tags: c#, ajax, json, mono, jsonresult

I want to return a JSON result. To do this I have a controller method as follows that is called from a `Ajax.BeginForm` on the View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Update",  new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "MySuccessMethod()" }))
{
    <!-- some form stuff -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

This is the controller that handles it:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Update(FormCollection fc)
{
    // Process form stuff
    return Json (new {success = true });
}
```

What I want is to process the success response with `MySuccessMethod`. What I see is that the view on submit goes to the correct controller method above, which then redirects the page to the URL `/Home/Update` with the following string in the screen:

> {"success": true }

Not sure if it is relevant but I am using Mono.

How can I make the framework not switch pages to `/Home/Update` nor display the JSON string on the view and just process the JSON in the back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, check the following:

1) Make sure you have [`Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/2.0.30506) included and referenced

2) `OnSuccess = "MySuccessMethod()"` should be `OnSuccess = "MySuccessMethod"` (where `MySuccessMethod` is a `JavaScript` method, not a `C#` one)

For your second question, you could have your method return `ActionResult` instead of `JsonResult` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for more information).  `JsonResult` is a type of `ActionResult`, which means that updating your action to return `ActionResult` will allow your method to return multiple types of `ActionResult` depending on the scenario:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeThing(int randomParam)
{
    if (randomParam == 0)
    { 
        return Json("Zero!"); 
    }
    else if (randomParam == 1)
    {
        return View("Not zero!");
    }
    else
    {
        return HttpNotFound("Error: I can only find zeroes and ones");
    }
}
```

As a general rule of thumb (although sometimes rules are meant to be broken), having your action return one type (like your example, `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult`) makes your action less error-prone as, for example, Visual Studio will let you know if you accidentally try to return another type of result - use `ActionResult` when your action returns more than one type of result.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to post a viewmodel to a controller using an ajax form?

Comment: Absolutely. You'll just have to make sure that the object you are passing to your controller via the form matches your viewmodel. An example can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871365/mvc3-passing-viewmodel-to-controller-method-using-jquery-ajax).

Comment: Yes thanks! Since the viewmodel has a two objects with lots of properties I decided to only use the primary key and the one value I am updating. Then I loop through a formcollection and update the database.

Is this a good decision or is there a better way?

Comment: There's no need to send each property of the viewmodel over to the controller if you're only updating one value, so your decision is valid.